# WebView not showing local content in release build

Tags: android, gradle, android-webview, proguard, dexprotector

I have a strange problem showing local data in `WebView`. In my project neither `loadData` nor `loadDataWithBaseUrl` just not working specifically in release build. Showing content from url with `loadUrl` working fine in both debug and release, but I need to show local data. The error is like:

`"Web page not available The web page at data:text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8;base64, could not be loaded because: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"`

There is a lot of questions on stackoverflow with this error, but all of them either address issues with encoding or specific to some Android version. I tried solutions from countless answers, but it only slightly changes text inside error (this part `data:text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8;base64`). Also in my case all android versions have a problem, and I'm not using any special symbols in html content or anything, just simplest possible document:

`<html><body>test</body></html>`

The only way that I was able to show local data in `WebView` is creating new project from scratch. In new project everything just works. So it's make me think issue is related to some project configuration. I don't know if it's something in gradle, proguard, dexprotector or anyting else.

Can anyone give some advice what it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling DexProtector's Public Key Pinning actually make it work. Now have to configure this somehow to work with Public Key Pinning.